# Как получить текущее время в секундах?

Tags: python-3.x, время

Мне нужно получить нынешнее время в секундах. Как я могу это сделать? С помощью `time.time()` я получаю неправильные данные, то есть не 2021 год, а 51 год.

Comment: Покажите, пожалуйста, как вы получаете 51 год?

Comment: S. Nick задал хороший вопрос. Моё предположение: Очень похоже, что просто пересчитывается количество секунд в года, дни. минуты и т.д. Просто не учитывается, что это отсчёт от начала Unix epoch. Или я ошибаюсь? Действительно, как получается?

Answer (score 1):

time.time() возвращает текущее время в секундах отсчитваемых от 1-го Января 00:00:00 1970 г. Отсюда и 51 год :-)
Определитесь от которой точки во времени вам нужно отсчитывать секунды и соответственно пересчитайте.
Откуда вам нужно время в секундах? От Рождества Христова, т.е. от начала нашей эры? Если, да то довольно муторное занятие, нужно будет обрабатывать високосные годы.

Answer (score 1):

Если считать от нашей эры,то

```
import datetime
(datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.datetime(1, 1, 1, 0, 0)).total_seconds()
```

Високосные года учитываются, но

Но всеравно не будет 2021 потому как наша эра началась в первом году. Нулевого никогда не было несмотря на ISO8601 и Питон его не поддерживает.

Хотя можно добавить виртуальный год

```
(datetime.datetime.now()-datetime.datetime(1,1,1)+ datetime.timedelta(days=366)).total_seconds()
```

738499 дней в итоге.

<s>Разделим эти дни на года тупым методом:</s>

```
>>> def ygen():
...   while True:
...     yield 366
...     yield 365
...     yield 365
...     yield 365
... 
>>> d = 738499
>>> yg=ygen()
>>> y=0
>>> while d>365:
...   d-=next(yg)
...   y+=1
... 
>>> y
2021
>>> d
328
```

И получается 2021 год и 328 дней от нулевого года - что-то маловато... гдето потерялась пара недель =) (сегодня 344 день)

```
>>> def vis(y):
...     if y % 400 == 0: return 366
...     if y % 100 == 0: return 365
...     if y % 4 == 0: return 366
...     return 365
... 
>>> 
>>> d = 738499
>>> y = 0
>>> 
>>> while d>=vis(y):
...     d -= vis(y)
...     y += 1
...
>>> d
343
>>> y
2021
```

343 дня прошло, идет 344ый - вроде все сошлось

Comment: не уверен, что високосные года будут правильно обработаны. Или будут?

Comment: а хотя будут! `datetime.datetime(2021, 12, 10) - datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 10)
datetime.timedelta(days=731)` но тут ещё где-то погрешность зарылась

Comment: Здорово! :-) !!